# Cannot print pdfs with images

Tags: printing, pdf

I can successfully print text files or webpages but when I print a pdf file with images, the printer does not print the images. In fact there is a white space instead of the image on the printed page!
I'd like to know what should I do in order to print the pdf file with the image.

I DON'T want to print the pdf to a file, using cups-pdf. I want to have a hard copy of my pdf file!

Comment: Please add information about your printer. This may be a printer driver issue.

Answer (score 0):

Dear using cup you can easily print pages with images

1. First install cups-pdf using

   sudo apt-get install cups-pdf
2. Print the PDF from "Evince" using the new PDF printer that is added by cups-pdf

   first. The output goes to ~/PDF (can be configured in /etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf).
3. Opened the pdf file generated by cups-pdf printer to Evince and printed it again to

   real printer.

**Note**

if you are facing problem with blank images still then reinstall purge

using these commands .

-sudo apt-get purge cups-pdf

-sudo apt-get install cups-pdf

-sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart

hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

I note that Evince converts to PS using Ghostscript (look for a CPU-hogging `gs` process after starting the print job).

Using `lpr` from the command line, on the other hand, uses `pdftops`. This combination seems to have fewer problems with large files.